# Landscape orientation issue

Tags: iphone

I have my app 98% complete but stumbled across an issue which is stumping me!
Any help would be great.

Basically....I have a 5 tab controller. I have done some remodelling on the first tab view so that moving it from portrait to landscape moves everything around so that it looks great.
The other 4 tabs also move from portrait to landscape and back with ease.

Now....the issue I stumbled across was that if I had say tab 5 in portrait, moved it to landscape and then tapped tab 1, the only bits in tab 1 that orientate to landscape are the bits i fixed in the sizing inspector.
The bits I've re-positioned in code won't landscape.

If I however turn that tab 1 portrait and then back to landscape, it works!

The label fields I've moved with code using .frame and CGRectMake is in the

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration: (NSTimeInterval)duration
```

method.

.......do I need to put some code in the AppDelegate which the TabController resides in??

It makes sense to me that the TabBarController knows the orientation.

When you tap a tab.....what method gets actioned first before the view loads??

I think I need to catch the orientation then, adjust my label positions and then load the view.......

I would appreciate any thoughts?

Gaz.

**EDIT:** It's like what I want to do is be able to change things in tab 1 if the orientation changes in other tabs.can you do that? It seems that the 5 tab views are separate...

Comment: try to check orientation in portrait mode. I remember that I faced the same problem and found this one..

Comment: ooppss wrote wrong.. i mean to say try to check orientation in viewWillAppear..and do your stuff based on that...

Answer (score 0):

Try making a call to your rotation method in your view controllers `viewWillAppear` method, checking for correct orientation, and moving what you need to move. Should look something like this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self autoRotate];
}
```

Comment: Thanks CL....I need to look into this......not entirely sure how this works mate........Gaz.

Comment: The problem enlies in that when you are not in the view controller, it doesn't receive the interface changes because it isn't visible. So only the view controller you are looking at gets the notification and switches. The ones that are created in interface builder are resized because of their connections of autoresizing, where as the ones you created programmatically aren't because they haven't been set up this way.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what's happening CL.....if I'm in tab 5's portrait view and turn it landscape, then hit tab 4, tab 3, tab 2 and tab 1...they all seem to know and are already in landscape when the view loads. Tab 1 where I have my problem actually goes landscape too but only on the autosized elements....not the moved elements. The code does work because when I turn portrait and then landscape in tab 1, the moved button and labels are where they should be. I have this code in the correct place I think.....what would be way forward on this mate?....Gaz.

Comment: Used the ViewWillAppear method and it worked a treat CL....thanks for your time!.....Gaz.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you move something in code it maintains it's position, so you need to change it's position every time the orientation changes in every view controller where you move objects in code. Like:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                            duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)){
         //change positions with animation using duration
    }else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)){
         //change positions with animation using duration
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Carles.....it's the strangest of things. When in the tab view I'm on about, it rotates absolutely great! It has a picker view, labels etc. Some rotate using the sizing inspector and the others I couldn't get right, I used code. But when I switch to another tab, go landscape and then come back to tab 1, only the sized items are landscape, not the coded items.....I'll give it a go mate!